# How would I use jQuery to grab the contents of a page and render it within a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is a question in response to thise: [Javascript AJAX function not working in IE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/760628/javascript-function-not-working-in-ie)

I need jQuery to do something like this:

```
function render_message(id)
{
var xmlHttp;
  xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();  
  xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
    if(xmlHttp.readyState==4)
      {
        document.getElementById('message').innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText;
        document.getElementById('message').style.display='';
        }
    }
    var url="include/javascript/message.php";
    url=url+"?q="+id;
  xmlHttp.open("GET",url,true);
  xmlHttp.send(null);
}
```

Can someone write the function for me quickly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the handy [`load()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/load#urldatacallback) function for this:

```
$('#message').load("include/javascript/message.php", {q: id}, function() {
    $(this).show();
});
```

The callback function is assuming the `message` div is hidden and you only want it show once the request is complete.

Answer (score 1):

See `$.ajax()` to retrieve pages and access the content.  [Documentation here](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax).

Then use e.g. `$("#yourElementId").html( myHtmlContent )` to replace the HTML.  [More doc here](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation).

Answer (score 0):

Use JQuery's $.load() function (http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/load):

```
$("#mydiv").load("a/url/here.html");
```